Access to file in S3 with Next.JS application via pre-signed URL does not work - blocked by CORS
I have created a pre-signed URL to a file in an S3 bucket to use it in my application. When I enter the pre-signed URL in the browser or call it in Powershell with curl I get the file back directly, which works as expected. But if I do the same in my application with an axios.get (code below) I get an error and no access to the file, blocked by the CORS.
I'm very new to AWS, but the S3 documentation says, as I understand it, that you can also get files via a program and without restriction by policies. "use presigned URLs to grant time-limited access to objects in Amazon S3 without updating your bucket policy. A presigned URL can be entered in a browser or used by a program to download an object."
What have I misunderstood/implemented incorrectly?
export async function handleS3(url: string) {
  axios
    .get(url)
    .then((response) => {
      // Hier verarbeiten wir die Antwort vom Server
      console.log('Daten erfolgreich geladen:', response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Fehlerbehandlung, falls die Anfrage fehlschlägt
      console.error('Fehler beim Laden der Daten:', error);
    });
}

This is the error I get in the console:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'pre-signed URL' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.


Go to S3 console
Click the S3 bucket where you've hosted you html page
Click Permissions and Scroll and Goto the Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) section

There you can see the CORS policy for that selected bucket.
If the localhost is not allowed there then click edit and update there.
The CORS policy looks something like this, you have to update the AllowedOrigins
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://www.example.com"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]


Thanks a lot, the change worked. But I thought with a pre-signed URL I could bypass settings in the S3 bucket, such as in the CORS. The user comes to the application with a URI or signed URL from his own S3 bucket, so I can't change anything in the settings of the S3 bucket in production. What alternative would I have to use then?

Aravindan vaithialingam's solution works and is correct, for my specific case where I don't want to customize the CORS the request has to come from the backend. If you fetch your data with the signed URL from the backend everything should work because its no longer blocked by CORS.

Hi @Fred do you happen to have an example of how you implemented the pre-sign in the NextJS app? using an API and route etc?
I'd love to see a Gist of getting up and running? Mine keeps 403-ing

Hi @TheLearningDev
the comment is to long for stack overflow, you can find it in the comment.txt in this repo. I hope i could help you out
https://github.com/EisenFred/stack-overflow-comment/blob/2b0edaa695350105c86ee9f5fbe4013b54b28313/comment.txt

Thank you that is really helpful!
